# Set iframe content to return value from fetch command

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I would like to set the content of an iframe on my html page to the response from a `fetch` command in js. I am currently using this code.

```
window.fetch(
        "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SXR0D3MzpBM?autoplay=0&mute=1", {
    method: 'GET',
    accept: 'text/html',
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);

    var iframe = document.getElementById('video');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(data);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
});
```

When i test this code, the iframe just displays

```
   [Object Response]
```

I would like to see an embedded youtube video in the iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is promise object you need to await or another `then`

```
.then(async (data) => {
    data = await data.text();
.....
```

but there is another problem, the response headers doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so you can't read the response. and the `mode: 'no-cors'` wont bypass CORS.